# vuetify v-select styling : too big

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to reduce the height of the v-select in Vuetify ?
I don't understand why this elements are so big / fat...
[image]

---

My code is :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-select
      outline
      dense
      v-model="filtresActivites"
      :items="activitesGroupees"
      item-text="activiteNomComplet"
      item-value="activiteCode"
      multiple
    >
      <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
        <span v-if="index === 0" class="deep-orange--text">{{ filtresActivites.length }} activités</span>
      </template>
    </v-select>
  </div>
</template>
```

"You can add height property to your v-select like this:" : it dosn't work

I added `.v-select__selections { min-height: 30px }` in the style of the component and it dosn't work.

Comment: Can you post your code ? We can't imagine it...

Comment: Apparently they are not designed to match the buttons, either try the large button or use css to change the v-select size https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#select

Comment: I tried to change the CSS but it's not easy. Ex; style="height:20px" in the v-select doesn't work.

Comment: I think you are looking for a the `v-overflow-btn`  https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/overflow-btns/

Answer (score 1):

You can add `height` property to your `v-select` like this:

```
<v-select
 :items="items"
 height=50
></v-select>
```

If you want to change the css property of `v-select`, you can do so by adding this class

```
.v-select__selections {
     min-height: 30px
}
```

The `min-height` is `42px` by default

It is also hard to understand your problem when we cannot see your code

Comment: Make sure to add the styles in App.vue. Otherwise it will get overwritten by the default styles. I tried your code in Codepen and `height=50` changed the height of `v-select`. Using `solo` property would also decrease the height. Another thing that would help is you can inspect the element and see which class is adding the height. copy the class name and change the height globally(i.e in App.vue)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use **outline** style in `v-select`. Remove it.

Image example from **vuetify**:
[image: the example image]